# Jenkinfile When Condition for env.JOB_NAME

Tags: linux, jenkins-pipeline

I have a `Jenkinsfile` I would like to trigger certain steps based on `env.JOB_NAME`. As a test I have done this;

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
pipeline {
    agent any
     stages {  
      stage('Get ID') {
          when {
              "${env.JOB_NAME}" == 'Notification Sender (dev)'
          }
       steps {
       echo "${env.JOB_NAME}"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However I get the error;

```
WorkflowScript: 6: Expected a when condition @ line 6, column 11.
             when {
             ^

WorkflowScript: 6: Empty when closure, remove the property or add some content. @ line 6, column 11.
             when {
             ^
```

Can I make the stage run based on the `env.JOB_NAME` using the `when` condition?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Try the following

```
when {
     expression {
         env.JOB_NAME == 'Notification Sender (dev)'
     }
}
```

There is full documentation on the [Pipeline syntax](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when) page, but the relevant part is

> **expression**
>   Execute the stage when the specified Groovy expression evaluates to true, for example: `when { expression { return params.DEBUG_BUILD } }`